# Embedding code snippets in posts with indentation

Tags: plugins, admin, visual-editor, code, syntax-highlighting

I have a privately hosted blog using WordPress, and I am using the SyntaxHighlighter Evolved plugin for displaying highlighted code snippets nicely.

I use the built-in editor in WordPress for writing my posts, but whenever I paste in code snippets, they lose all the formatting they had (indentation). This makes it very hard to create code snippets and share on my blog.

Am i missing anything? Is there any easy way to paste code snippets while keeping their formatting ?

For example, see what code that was indented correctly shows up in the WP editor (lost all indentation):

[image]

Comment: Use `<pre>` element.

Comment: @cybmeta how do i use it exactly ?

Comment: Switch to "Text" tab in editor. Although if plugin is involved there might be more to it.